# Link preview not appearing in LinkedIn posts made using Pardot LinkedIn Social Media Connector

Tags: pardot, social, linkedin

When a social post is made to LinkedIn (either an individual account or company page), the link preview on the post doesn't work if the post has been made using the Pardot LinkedIn Social Media Connector.

**Here's what it looks like if you make the post using Hootsuite, or post directly on LinkedIn**:

[image]

**Here's what it looks like if you make the post using Pardot**:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? Is anybody else having the same trouble?

Posts to Facebook and Twitter work fine. It just seems to be LinkedIn posts that have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have just heard back from Pardot that this is a known issue as at July 2017, possibly resulting from a switch to v2 of the LinkedIn API. The Pardot team is currently scoping this to see what would be required to implement a solution.